# VHDL - FPGA4U - Get Switch Values

Tags: vhdl, fpga, quartus

I want to get the `Switch0` value to show on the LEDs.

Here's My Entity :

```
port(
   switchA : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
);
```

And here's my custom type:

```
type text_type is array (0 to 7) of std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
signal text, nexttext, shiftedtext : text_type;
signal countertext, nextcountertext: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
```

I tried this code but it doesn't work!

```
if(button_n(0)='1')then

nextstate<=Finish;
countertext <= (0 to 7 => switchA , others => '0');           --- Get SwitchA Value!! ---
end if;
```

Here's a FPGA4U Board image : [FPGA4U Board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyvgN.png)

And at the end, here's an example for enabling some LEDs

```
when names1 =>
nextstate<=test2;
nextcountertext<=(others=>'0');
nexttext <=("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"0000000001111100011111110000111000100010000000000000000000000000",
"0000000000010000100010001001000100110010000000000000000000000000",
"0000000000010000100010001001111100101010000000000000000000000000",
"0000000000010000100010001001000100100110000000000000000000000000",
"0000000001111100100010001001000100100010000000000000000000000000");

-- This Code Show "IMAN" on The LEDs!!
```

Can anyone help me please? I'm really confused.

Comment: The code that doesn't work is an isolated fragment. In the right context, it might work. Please post a minimal compilable example.

Answer (score -1):

`countertext` is a signal that shows you which level(state) you are in;
Eg. if you are in "IMAN" text writing level(it's your first text), nextcountertext will be contertext+1 (=2), and in each level you can check the level you are in, and save the order of showing messages.

Comment: Please don't use cellphone abbreviations.